# Include jquery ui function in plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am wondering how I can include the drag functionality from the jquery UI library in a separate plugin I am modifying. I want to make a div draggable, but don't want to have to write my own method.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest building the plugin as a jquery ui widget and just making the jquery ui draggable widget a dependency of your widget. then you make your div draggable using $(div).draggable();.